# Erro de sintaxe if em script csh

Tags: bash

Quando tento executar o script, obtenho esse erro:

```
$ ./install
$ if: Expression Syntax.
```

Estou tentando instalar o `Altera Complete Design Suite 7.2`, no `Debian GNU/Linux 7, Kernel Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae`, com `csh versão 20110502-2.1`.

Excerto do script:

```csh
#!/bin/csh
#  Altera Tools Install Script
.
.
.

unalias *

if ( $?QINST_VERBOSE ) then
    set expert_mode = 1
else
    set expert_mode = 0
endif


if ( $?QINST_DEBUG ) then
    set debug = 1
else
    set debug = 0
endif

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

O correto seria:

```
if ( $?QINST_VERBOSE ) 
then
    set expert_mode = 1
else
    set expert_mode = 0
fi


if ( $?QINST_DEBUG ) 
then
    set debug = 1
else
    set debug = 0
fi
```